# Identification of 14-pin IC from Microchip

Tags: identification

I am sorting my shop and found a stick of ICs:

[image]

The markings on the top side are

> 3636
>
> CWSA
>
> 'Microchip logo', 'another logo'

Is there a way to identify this chip?

Comment: The identification text is usually on the other side? Is the other side blank?

Comment: If the markings are on the bottom, I'd suspect they are counterfiet and throw them away.   Of the thousands, 10's of thousands or maybe more IC's I've seen, exactly zero were marked on the BOTTOM.

Comment: Question is corrected now. The view in the figure is the top side. On the bottom side are no markings

Comment: Maybe a security chip of some kind. Perhaps you can do a digital search of your purchase orders.

Comment: I did. the only chipset with this amount are CAP1298 https://www.mouser.at/datasheet/2/268/00001571B-1859501.pdf but the other ICs I have are marked with 'CAP1298' and the same MC logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a hint from the comments I was able to identify the ICs. I traced my orders and only a few chips with this amount, package, pins, design and manufacturer remain.

They are [CAP1298](https://www.mouser.at/datasheet/2/268/00001571B-1859501.pdf) capacitive proximity sensors. On p. 60 are the markings of the different variations listed. Apparently these are production and traceability numbers.

I ordered a few shortly after they became accessible, therefore my existing stock may have different markings.